# Distribution mean equal to std, Model Selection

Tags: maximum-likelihood, mean, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

One day, I got strange statistics from my data. That shows the mean equals to std (one-dimensional dataset).

Then, I researched the information, I got the following.

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75244/mean-and-std-deviation-of-a-population-equal

According to this, this kind of distribution is called

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distributions

I thought I was able to use an exponential distribution for modeling, though, my data is actually counted. In other words, they are not a period of time. I think exponential distribution is good for the dataset for some period of time, right? For example, waiting time for bus and stuff like that.

Now, you might not be able to understand what I want to tell, sorry for my English.

My question is that Can I assume an exponential distribution and do MLE with count dataset? I think I should postulate Poisson.

Comment: The Poisson is a count distribution with (population) mean = standard deviation.

Comment: "mean = stand deviation" is correct for exponential distribution, not for Poisson distribution. For Poisson distribution, mean = variance, not stand deviation.